# View original full-resolution image in Aperture 2.0

Tags: preview, aperture, resolution

I want to do the comparison of image quality of 2 lenses, with different settings. For this purpose I need to do the pixel level comparison.
But Aperture stores originals of the files internally showing to the user only previews, that are generated according to the Aperture preferences. Currently I have it set to maximum quality and half of original resolution.

But I want to compare not previews but originals, to see the difference most precisely, at full resolution. Is there any easy way to look at originals and not previews? Or do I have to change the Aperture preferences to full resolution and then regenerate previews? And if I change preferences, will the previews for my whole library get recreated, or only the ones that I manually force to regenerate previews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you can just go to the view Menu. And toggle the 'Show Original Image'

[image: think]

This will stick a label on the image so you know you are seeing an Original rather than a Preview.

[image]

The setting is global by the looks of it. And works in the compare mode.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't change my image at all. The number of pixels stays unchanged. I think that this setting just shows the original image if I applied any adjustments, or the image is a version. But doesn't really show full-resolution original image.

Comment: The only thing is when I open an exported original file I see no difference with the one in the aperture screen and the Photoshop one.

Comment: Have a look at Viewing Images at Full Resolution http://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=6%26section=8 and also working with preview images http://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=6%26section=15  which show you how to turn them off

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. They were very helpful. For some reason the generated previews originally had full resolution, that's why they didn't differ from original image. But that is different question. Thank you again.